# What can I do to fix SQL error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Tags: sql, exists

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get the lest subquery in the SELECT to work and Just cannot figure out a way for it to give me any kind of output just for the last one. Code works without it.

```
SELECT U.Username, COUNT(DISTINCT P.PostID) AS 'Total Posts',
           CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL((SELECT SUM(R.Upvote) FROM Ratings R WHERE U.UserID = R.FK_UserID), 0)) AS 'Karma',
           CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL((SELECT U.UserID, SUM(R.Upvote) FROM Users JOIN Posts ON Posts.FK_UserID = UserID
               JOIN Ratings ON Ratings.FK_PostID = PostID GROUP BY UserID), 0)) AS 'Total Karma Received'
    FROM Users U
    FULL OUTER JOIN Ratings R on U.UserID = R.FK_UserID
    FULL OUTER JOIN Posts P on U.UserID = P.FK_UserID
    GROUP BY U.Username, U.UserID
    ORDER BY 'Total Posts' DESC
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: @Kendle, my parsing gets a syntax error before I come to that part. Need to switch grammar.

Comment: @Kendle, my first comment was a rhetorical question, meant to encourage OP to always add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery expression for 'Total Karma Received' should return only one value, but your subquery: **SELECT U.UserId, SUM(R.UpVote)...GROUP BY UserId** is poised to return at least two values (UserId and a Sum), but also multiple rows. What is it supposed to return: 'Total UpVotes for all Users', or 'Total UpVotes for this User', or ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can move `userID` to a **WHERE** in the inner query if you only want the upvotes for this user, or remove it entirely if you want the sum of all upvotes for all users.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   U.Username, 
>   COUNT(DISTINCT P.PostID) AS 'Total Posts',
>   CONVERT(CHAR(10), 
>           ISNULL(
>              (SELECT SUM(R.Upvote) 
>               FROM Ratings R 
>               WHERE U.UserID = R.FK_UserID),
>           0)) AS 'Karma',
>   CONVERT(CHAR(10), 
>           ISNULL(
>               (SELECT  SUM(R.Upvote) 
>                FROM Users 
>                JOIN Posts ON Posts.FK_UserID = UserID
>                JOIN Ratings ON Ratings.FK_PostID = PostID 
>                WHERE UserID = U.UserID 
>                GROUP BY UserID), 
>            0)) AS 'Total Karma Received'
> FROM Users U
> FULL OUTER JOIN Ratings R on U.UserID = R.FK_UserID
> FULL OUTER JOIN Posts P on U.UserID = P.FK_UserID
> GROUP BY U.Username, U.UserID
> ORDER BY 'Total Posts' DESC;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d7653c45c3f16f94f4d5ee8f18add0a)*

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler and more efficient to join to the tables than to run a sub-query per row.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   U.userID,
>   U.Username, 
>   COUNT(DISTINCT P.PostID) AS 'Total Posts',
>   SUM(given.upvote) AS 'Total Karma Given',
>   SUM(recd.upvote) AS 'Total Karma Received' 
> FROM Users U
> LEFT JOIN posts P
> ON U.userID = P.FK_UserID
> LEFT JOIN ratings recd
> ON P.postID= recd.FK_PostID
> LEFT JOIN ratings given
> ON U.userID = given.FK_UserID
> GROUP BY U.userID,U.username
> ORDER BY U.userID,U.username
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> userID | Username   | Total Posts | Total Karma Given | Total Karma Received
> -----: | :--------- | ----------: | ----------------: | -------------------:
>      1 | user one   |           2 |              null |                    1
>      2 | user two   |           1 |              null |                 null
>      3 | User Three |           0 |              null |                 null
>      4 | User Four  |           0 |                 1 |                 null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecff451a6d9934ecdb526a18243a93f5)*

Answer (score 0):

one of your sub queries return more than one record, though you get the error.
some thing like this:

```
SELECT A.*,
   CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL(SUM(R.Upvote), '0')) AS 'Total KarmaReceived' FROM (
SELECT U.Username,
       COUNT(DISTINCT P.PostID) AS 'Total Posts',
       CONVERT(CHAR(10),
               ISNULL(
               (
                   SELECT SUM(R.Upvote)FROM Ratings R WHERE U.UserID = R.FK_UserID
               ),
               0
                     )
              ) AS 'Karma'
FROM Users U
    FULL OUTER JOIN Ratings R
        ON U.UserID = R.FK_UserID
    FULL OUTER JOIN Posts P
        ON U.UserID = P.FK_UserID
GROUP BY U.Username,
         U.UserID) A
JOIN Posts
    ON Posts.FK_UserID = A.UserID
JOIN Ratings
    ON Ratings.FK_PostID = PostID GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: What do you suggest that the OP should do to solve the problem?

Comment: may be he should write the query first without the second sub query and then join the first query with that subquery.

Comment: Please put the query that you suggest in your answer.

Comment: not sure but something like this: `SELECT A.*, CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL(SUM(R.Upvote), '0')) AS 'TKR' FROM (SELECT U.Username,COUNT(DISTINCT P.PostID) AS 'TP',CONVERT(CHAR(10),ISNULL((SELECT SUM(R.Upvote)FROM Ratings R WHERE U.UserID = R.FK_UserID),0)) AS 'K' FROM Users U FULL OUTER JOIN Ratings R ON U.UserID = R.FK_UserID FULL OUTER JOIN Posts P ON U.UserID = P.FK_UserID GROUP BY U.Username, U.UserID) A JOIN Posts ON Posts.FK_UserID = A.UserID JOIN Ratings ON Ratings.FK_PostID = PostID GROUP BY UserID;`

Comment: Put it in your answer. Try it on DBfiddle and put the link in your answer.